# Segmentation fault when freeing String in a Struct - C

Tags: c, malloc

I've been stuck on a segmentation fault of a long time. I declared a struct with a pointer to a string. I wrote two functions, create and remove to manipulate values. The struct is as follows:

```
#include "filename.h"  
//*in filename.h:* typedef struct linkNode linkNode_t;

struct linkNode{
    struct linkNode *next;
    char *value;
};
```

The create function will first allocate memory for the node, then allocate memory for the value, and then copy the input value into the value field:

```
linkNode_t* create(char* stuff){
    linkNode_t *ptr=malloc(sizeof(linkNode_t));
    if(ptr==NULL){
        printf("malloc failure");
        return NULL;
    }
    char* tempvalu=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(stuff)+1);
    if(tempvalu==NULL){
        printf("malloc failure");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(tempvalu,stuff);
    ptr->next=NULL;
    ptr->value=tempvalu;
    return ptr;
}
```

A function is used to insert a node into the linked list:

```
linkNode_t* insertLast(linkNode_t* start, linkNode_t* newNode){
    linkNode_t* current=start;
    while(current->next!=NULL){
        current=current->next;
    }
//now current points to the last element in the linked list
    current->next=newNode;
    return start;
}
```

The part causing me problem is as follows:

```
linkNode_t* removebyValue(linkNode_t* start, char* valu){
/**removes the first instance of a node with a certain value. Return *start after     removing.
    if linked list becomes empty, return NULL*/

    linkNode_t *current=start;
    linkNode_t *previous=start;
    while(current!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(valu,current->value)==0) {//found the node to delete
            if(current==start){//removing the head
                linkNode_t* retvalue= current->next;
                free(current->value);
                free(current);
                return retvalue;
            }
            else{   //removing other elements in the linked list
                previous->next=current->next;
                free(current->value);
                free(current);
                return start;
            }
        }
        else{
            previous=current;
            current=current->next;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

In the Main I created a linked list of two elements,1 and 2, and tried to free element 1 when segmentation fault occured.

```
int main(){
    linkNode_t *pt1=create("1");
    pt1=insertLast(pt1,create("2"));
    removebyValue(pt1,"1"); //Causes seg fault. If I replace "1" by "2" nothing happens
```

Can someone give some suggestions on this? Thanks in advance

EDIT: I put all the code that could be related since someone said the sections I put on didn't have an error

Comment: Side note, there should be brackets around `strlen(stuff)+1`.

Comment: @slugonamission : only if `(sizeof(char) != 1)` ...

Comment: I have just put your pieces together to a program that compiles, and it doesn't crash, so I suspect you've removed the bit that causes it to crash...

Comment: Before I post anything, I'm trying to understand what the *return* value of this `remove()` function is supposed to be. Is it *always* supposed to be a pointer to the node (if any) that follows the deleted node? When not passing in the head-pointer by address for possible modification, usually the active head pointer is always returned, thereby allowing you to write `pt = remove(pt, "1");`. But you can't do that if the node deleted is not the front node in your list. So I'm a little lost.

Comment: @WhozCraig The remove function should take the head pointer as an input, and return the head(new head) pointer as an output. I updated my code to the complete version just now, hope that helps a little. thanks!

Comment: @wildplasser - of course, but I like to take precautions over some things.

Comment: @slugonamission: In C, sizeof (char) is **always** 1. It's CHAR_BIT that might differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking the removal of a node while maintaining the start pointer properly. Consider a hopefully simpler approach.

```
typedef struct node_t 
{
    struct node_t* next;
    char* value;
} node_t;

node_t* remove(node_t *start, const char* valu)
{
    node_t* current=start;
    node_t* prev=NULL;

    while(current && strcmp(current->value, valu))
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current)
    {
        if (prev) // we're not deleting start node
            prev->next = current->next;

        else      // we *are* deleting start node
            start = current->next;

        // now the node is unlinked. remove it.
        free(current->value);
        free(current);
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: My code works now. Turns out I forgot to assign the output of remove to my linked list pointer. And when I tried to print it seg fault came out. Such a stupid error. Thanks for the help tho!!

Answer (score 1):

here's an alternative test code that works fine, take a loot at it and see if it helps.
in addition, you can add

```
typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t* next;
    char* value;
} node;
```

this may appear simpler to understand, but it isn't because nature of typedef is confusing.
I STRONGLY suggest you take a look at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/CodingStyle
This is the coding style of the linux kernel, it is very short and simple, not particularly a law, but it is worth noting...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node_t {
    struct node_t* next;
    char* value;
};

struct node_t* create(const char* istr) 
{
    struct node_t* ptr = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    char* tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(istr) + 1));

    strcpy(tmp, istr);
    ptr->next = 0;
    ptr->value = tmp;
    return ptr;
}

struct node_t* remove(struct node_t* start, const char* value)
{
    struct node_t* current = start;
    struct node_t* prev = start;

    while (current != 0) {
        if (!strcmp(value, current->value)) {
            if (current == start) {
                struct node_t* retval = current->next;
                free(current->value);
                free(current);
                return retval;
            } else {
                /* nothing happens */
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    struct node_t* pt = create("1");
    printf("%s\n", pt->value);
    pt->next = create("2");
    printf("%s\n", pt->next->value);
    remove(pt, "1");    

    return 0;
}
```